# Why can't I print all the character types of variables in array?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    
    char name[20];
    int age[20], i, size;
    
    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
    printf("\nEnter Student # %d name: ", i+1 );
    scanf("%s", &name[i]);
    
    printf("\nEnter Student # %d age: ", i+1 );
    scanf ("\n%d", &age[i]);
    }
    printf("---");
    printf("\n Student Information");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent # %d :\n", i+1);
        printf("Name: %c", name[i]); //how do i print the array here?
        printf("\nAge: %d", age[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, I can't display the whole characters that are inputted, and instead, my program produces nothing. What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when `size` is greater than 20?

Comment: First of all, you should declare 2-dimensional arrays for student name like name[10][20] firs 10 represents the number of student and 20 represents each student name characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starboy_b already answered your question, but I want to highlight security issues in your code:

Keep in mind that using scanf to get input like you do is introducing dangerous vulnerabilities to your program.

Why? :
scanf does not know how much allocated space your variables have and does not prevent the user from entering more characters than your buffer can contain. This lead to buffer overflow and can be used to run attacker code.

Your better off e.g. using readline or fgets to get input from user.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

char name[20][100];
int age[20], i, size;

printf("Enter number of students: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{   
printf("\nEnter Student # %d name: ", i+1 );
scanf("%s", &name[i]);

printf("\nEnter Student # %d age: ", i+1 );
scanf ("\n%d", &age[i]);
}
printf("---");
printf("\n Student Information");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("\nStudent # %d :\n", i+1);
    printf("Name: %s", name[i]); //how do i print the array here?
    printf("\nAge: %d", age[i]);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your answer if you explain fully why your code differs from the OP's. You may sense that the OP can understand the differences but there could be many out there who later read your answer and don't understand.